# SQLite in table no such column quantite_stock

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I have created a table in SQLite in android with all columns and the logcat says that no such column `quatite_stock` in table `produittable` please tell me what's wrong. The column is there why it tells me the opposite

here is my logcat

```
05-15 23:15:28.595: E/AndroidRuntime(807): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-15 23:15:28.595: E/AndroidRuntime(807): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table produittable has no column named quantite_stock (code 1): , while compiling: insert into produittable(nom_produit,quantite_stock,prix_vente,description_produit) values('salah','l','b','kgamj')
05-15 23:15:28.595: E/AndroidRuntime(807):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
05-15 23:15:28.595: E/AndroidRuntime(807):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:882)
05-15 23:15:28.595: E/AndroidRuntime(807):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:493)
05-15 23:15:28.595: E/AndroidRuntime(807):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
05-15 23:15:28.595: E/AndroidRuntime(807):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
05-15 23:15:28.595: E/AndroidRuntime(807):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
05-15 23:15:28.595: E/AndroidRuntime(807):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.executeSql(SQLiteDatabase.java:1663)
05-15 23:15:28.595: E/AndroidRuntime(807):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQLiteDatabase.java:1594)
05-15 23:15:28.595: E/AndroidRuntime(807):  at tabet.salah.gvente.ProduitActivity.insert(ProduitActivity.java:165)
```

and for my Activity containing the Database

```
public class ProduitActivity extends Activity{
    SQLiteDatabase db;   
    @Override       
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.produits);
        createDB();
        TextView listeprod =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.link_to_liste);
        listeprod.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ChecklisteProduit.class);
                startActivity(i); 
            } 
            });

        Button btnAnnuler=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnAnnuler );
        btnAnnuler.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AndroidDashboardDesignActivity.class);
            startActivity(i); 
        } 
        });
      //inserer les information du produit dans la table produittable avec la methode insert
        Button btnAjout=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnAjout );
        btnAjout.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View arg0) {

        insert();
        } 
        });
        Button btnClear=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnClear );
        btnClear.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
        clear();
        }
        }); 
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    CreateMenu(menu);
    return true;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
    {
    return MenuChoice(item);
    }

    private void CreateMenu(Menu menu)
    {
    MenuItem mnu1 = menu.add(0, 0, 0, "Insert");
    {
    mnu1.setAlphabeticShortcut('i');
    mnu1.setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_input_add);
    }
    MenuItem mnu2 = menu.add(0, 1, 1, "Search");
    {
    mnu2.setAlphabeticShortcut('s');
    mnu2.setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_search_category_default);

    }
    MenuItem mnu3 = menu.add(0, 2, 2, "Delete");
    {
    mnu3.setAlphabeticShortcut('d');
    mnu3.setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_delete);

    }
    MenuItem mnu4 = menu.add(0, 3, 3, "View");
    {
    mnu4.setAlphabeticShortcut('d');
    mnu4.setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_info_details);
    }
    }
    private boolean MenuChoice(MenuItem item)
    {
    Intent intent=new Intent();
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case 0:
    insert();
    return true;
    case 1:
     intent.setClass(ProduitActivity.this, StockActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    return true;
    case 2:
     intent.setClass(ProduitActivity.this, StockActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    return true;

    case 3:
     intent.setClass(ProduitActivity.this, StockActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    return true;

    }
    return false;
    }
    public void createDB()
    {
    db=openOrCreateDatabase("produitbase.db", SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY, null);
    db.setLocale(Locale.getDefault());
    db.setLockingEnabled(true);
    db.setVersion(1);
    String sql="create table if not exists Produittable(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, nom_produit TEXT, quantite_stock TEXT, prix_vente TEXT, description_produit TEXT)";
    db.execSQL(sql);
    }

    public void insert()
    {
     EditText nom_produit=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.Nom_produit);
     EditText quantite_stock=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.quantite_stock);
     EditText prix_vente=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.prix_vente);
     EditText description_produit=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.description_produit);

     if(nom_produit.getText().toString().equals(""))
    {
    Toast.makeText(ProduitActivity.this, "Entrer nom produit.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    else if (quantite_stock.getText().toString().equals(""))
    {
    Toast.makeText(ProduitActivity.this, "Entrer la quantité.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    else if (prix_vente.getText().toString().equals(""))
    {
    Toast.makeText(ProduitActivity.this, "Entrer prix de vente.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    else if (description_produit.getText().toString().equals(""))
    {
    Toast.makeText(ProduitActivity.this, "Entrer la description.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    else 
    {

    String sql="insert into produittable(nom_produit,quantite_stock,prix_vente,description_produit) values('"+ nom_produit.getText().toString() +"','"+ quantite_stock.getText().toString() +"','"+ prix_vente.getText().toString() +"','"+ description_produit.getText().toString()+"')";
    db.execSQL(sql);
    clear();
    Toast.makeText(ProduitActivity.this, "Produit Ajouté.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } 
    }
    public void clear()
    {
     EditText nom_produit=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.Nom_produit);
    EditText quantite_stock=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.quantite_stock);
    EditText prix_vente=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.prix_vente);
    EditText description_produit=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.description_produit);

    nom_produit.setText("");
    quantite_stock.setText(""); 
    prix_vente.setText("");
    description_produit.setText("");

    nom_produit.clearFocus();
    quantite_stock.clearFocus();
    prix_vente.clearFocus();
    description_produit.clearFocus();

    nom_produit.requestFocus();
  }
@Override
    public void onDestroy()
    {
    super.onDestroy();
    db.close();
    }   
}
```

Comment: I see you used "CREATE IF EXISTS" to create your table. Is there any chance that the table was previously created without this column and the query you are running is against the old database?

Comment: the solution is to refrech the database by deleting it in the DDMS of eclipse and run the application this will be run correctly .. and thinks to your answer and you sur